# save(flush: true) is not flushing the session

Tags: hibernate, session, grails, transactions, grails-orm

I was creating a new grails app with several domain classes and controllers. All my controllers have working methods for save(), update() and list(), e.g.

```
def update(Long id, Long version) {
    def crawlerConfigInstance = CrawlerConfig.get(id)
    if (!crawlerConfigInstance) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'crawlerConfig.label', default: 'CrawlerConfig'), id])
        redirect(action: "list")
        return
    }

    if (version != null) {
        if (crawlerConfigInstance.version > version) {
            crawlerConfigInstance.errors.rejectValue("version", "default.optimistic.locking.failure",
                    [message(code: 'crawlerConfig.label', default: 'CrawlerConfig')] as Object[],
                    "Another user has updated this CrawlerConfig while you were editing")
            render(view: "edit", model: [crawlerConfigInstance: crawlerConfigInstance])
            return
        }
    }

    crawlerConfigInstance.properties = params

    if (!crawlerConfigInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        render(view: "edit", model: [crawlerConfigInstance: crawlerConfigInstance])
        return
    }

    flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'crawlerConfig.label', default: 'CrawlerConfig'), crawlerConfigInstance.id])
    redirect(action: "show", id: crawlerConfigInstance.id)
}
```

which is actually an autogenerated / scaffolded method by IDE

However, now I was adding an additional controller method which should run through a list of domain objects and update them accordingly. Getting the list, changing the attributes and validation is successfull.

save(flush:true) doesn't throw any errors and returns the updated domain object, as expected. However, checking the hibernate SQL statements, all I see is SELECTS, no update. In fact, if I directly call a delete() on the domain object after the save(), I get a concurrent transaction exception on the domain object.

My controller method looks like

```
def doSomething() {     

    def results = CrawlerConfig.findAll(bQ)

    results.each { crawlerConfigInstance ->

            crawlerConfigInstance.needsReview = true

            if (!crawlerConfigInstance.save(flush:  true)) {
                render(view: "show", model: [crawlerConfigInstance: crawlerConfigInstance])
                return
            }
    }

    redirect(action: "list")
}
```

Pretty straightforward. If I check for the dirty fields, needsReview is marked as dirty before the save(). save() updates the version on the object.

I currently still use h2:mem as database.

For me it looks like the transaction is not finished. But I don't get why or how I can get it to finish.

Thx in advance

**EDIT after POST from Ondrej**

created a Service (which gets injected and called fine)

```
package lizard
```

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional

@Transactional
class CrawlerConfigPersistenceService {

```
static transactional = true

def checkRequirementsForCrawlerConfigList(String query) {

    def results = CrawlerConfig.findAll(query)

    results.each { crawlerConfigInstance ->

        crawlerConfigInstance.needsReview = true

        if (!crawlerConfigInstance.save(flush: true)) {
            println crawlerConfigInstance.errors.getAllErrors()
            return
        }

    }
}
}
```

But this results in exactly the same behaviour, everything looks OK, except that there is no update statement raised by hibernate

Comment: things I forgot to mention: I'm using currently grails 2.1.1, creating new Objects in Database even in Controller works, just not updating existing ones.

Comment: what happens when you forcibly call session.flush()? Do you see the db writes or some other error popping up?

Comment: Nope nothing. When I call executeUpdate() it forcibly gets written. But never when I call save. I even tried to open a transaction on the hibernate session mysqlf, which failed badly.

Answer (score 0):

Move your methods for save(), update() and list() from Controllers to Services. Before doing it, have a look here and read the Services chapter: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/services.html

Comment: Understood, but why is it working for my save(), update() and list() methods, but not for the newly created one. These are also not encapsulated in a service, as autogenerated.

Comment: I followed the tip from Ondrej (thx for that) which results in a service (updated original post). However, the service has exactly the same behaviour, not calling any update statements

Comment: Could you try to change DataSource.groovy: change dbCreate to "update" for dev environment.
And, try to add failOnError:true as a parameter to the save method.

Comment: sure. I changed the settings as proposed: no change in behaviour and no exceptions during save.
Additionally I switched to mysql db driver which resulted in the same behaviour. no updates.

Comment: even a manual flush of the hibernate session isn't doing the trick

Comment: I extracted a service method for updating from my controller, which I now call from the working controller method and from my not working service method. The domain objects and dirty fields look the same. The update from the already working controller method *still works*. Saving my object from the non working service method is *still not working*.
What is wrong with my domain object?

Comment: What I can see from the get object SQL statements before the save, is that they are different: The working one does a query by ID (which results in the exact object to update). The non working one queries by 2 attributes w/o id, results in same single object though